# How can we track a video file duration in PHP

Tags: php

Hi I need to save video file duration. when it is uploaded. How can I do that in PHP.

Comment: you can either read it from the file directly or use some library. To google for "PHP video file duration" will surely help. Every PHP learner should learn to google as well. In both cases it's not a programming related question.

Answer (score 6):

Copy/Paste from a script I wrote a while ago:

```
$videofile="/var/video/user_video.avi";
ob_start();
passthru("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i \"{$videofile}\" 2>&1");
$duration = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$search='/Duration: (.*?),/';
$duration=preg_match($search, $duration, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);

echo $matches[1][0];
```

Comment: Don't use output buffering and passthru() to retrieve the result of a command, use backticks, exec or proc_open instead.

Comment: Sjoerd, indeed I should've reread that script prior to posting it.

Answer (score 0):

If the information is available in the extended information (such as id3 tags) you can use the id3 library to get the information...

http://getid3.sourceforge.net/

It also enables you to get the height and width of the video.